# Find frequency of subsets amongst multiple sets

Tags: python, set, subset

I have a list of skills as follows:

```
skills = ['Listening', 'Written_Expression','Clerical',
         'Night_Vision', 'Accounting']
```

I have a separate list of sets, each of which contains the skills related to a particular job:

```
job_skills =  
     [{'Listening','Written_Expression','Clerical','Night_Vision'},
     {'Chemistry','Written_Expression','Clerical','Listening'},
     .
     .
     ]
```

I want to count the frequency with which each combination of 2 unique skills is a subset of a set in job_skills and return a list of lists/sets with the combinations and frequencies as follows:

```
skill_pairs = [{'Listening', 'Written_Expression', 2},
              {'Listening', 'Clerical', 2},
              .
              .
              {'Night_Vision', 'Accounting', 0}]
```

At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
skill_combos = []
for idx, i in enumerate(skills):
    for jdx, j in enumerate(skills[idx+1:]):
        temp = []
        for job in range(len(job_skills)):
            temp.append(set([i,j]).issubset(job_skills[job])
        skill_combos.append([i,j,sum(temp)])
```

This gets the job done but its slow given that I have approx half a million skill combinations. Is there a faster way of doing this? Ideally not using 3 loops.

Thanks

Comment: This might be a good candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You only need to count the combinations that are present, the rest is zero, for example:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

job_skills = [{'Listening', 'Written_Expression', 'Clerical', 'Night_Vision'},
              {'Chemistry', 'Written_Expression', 'Clerical', 'Listening'}]


counts = Counter(combo for skill_set in job_skills for combo in combinations(skill_set, 2))

for key, value in counts.items():
    print(key, value)
```

**Output**

```
('Clerical', 'Written_Expression') 2
('Clerical', 'Listening') 2
('Clerical', 'Night_Vision') 1
('Written_Expression', 'Listening') 2
('Written_Expression', 'Night_Vision') 1
('Listening', 'Night_Vision') 1
('Clerical', 'Chemistry') 1
('Written_Expression', 'Chemistry') 1
('Listening', 'Chemistry') 1
```

See [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). If you want a dictionary that returns 0 for the ones that are missing, wrap `counts` with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
total = defaultdict(int)
total.update(counts)
print(total[('Night_Vision', 'Accounting')])
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is faster but you can use combinations with a Counter. My solution only calculates the combinations once. Then it uses the `issubset` notation.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

skills = ['Listening', 'Written_Expression','Clerical',
         'Night_Vision', 'Accounting']
job_skills = [{'Listening','Written_Expression','Clerical','Night_Vision'}, {'Chemistry','Written_Expression','Clerical','Listening'}]

pairs = {frozenset(x) for x in combinations(skills, 2)}
c = Counter(pair for pair in pairs for job in job_skills if pair.issubset(job))

for pair in pairs: # Adding the pairs that had no matches
    if pair not in c:
        c[pair] = 0

for key, count in c.items():
    print(key, count)
```

Output:

```
frozenset({'Written_Expression', 'Clerical'}) 2
frozenset({'Listening', 'Clerical'}) 2
frozenset({'Written_Expression', 'Listening'}) 2
frozenset({'Written_Expression', 'Night_Vision'}) 1
frozenset({'Listening', 'Night_Vision'}) 1
frozenset({'Clerical', 'Night_Vision'}) 1
frozenset({'Written_Expression', 'Accounting'}) 0
frozenset({'Clerical', 'Accounting'}) 0
frozenset({'Listening', 'Accounting'}) 0
frozenset({'Night_Vision', 'Accounting'}) 0
```